# PyGame - how to draw images in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm making a Brick Breaker game in PyGame. Everything worked just fine, until I wanted to exchange "rectangle bricks" with the images. I try to add them to the list using nested for loop and then draw the list. However, each of them is printed on the top of the other. What shall I change? Thanks in advance, here's the code

```
def create_bricks(self):
    self.bricks = []
    self.brick = pygame.image.load("brick.png")
    self.brick_rect = self.brick.get_rect() 
    y_pos = 30
    for i in range(5):
        x_pos = 50
        for j in range(8):
            self.brick_rect.center = (x_pos, y_pos)
            self.bricks.append(self.brick_rect)
            x_pos += 60
        y_pos += 20

def draw_bricks(self):
    for brick in self.bricks:
        self.screen.blit(brick, self.brick_rect)
```

Should I use screen.blits instead of blit? What about the arguments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are constantly modifying the rect of the same object. That can’t work.

Instead create a list of coordinates and blit the same image to different destinations based on that list.